# How do I see images in Windows Explorer (Windows 7) Name column as pictures rather than generic icons?

Tags: windows-7, images, thumbnails

I've read all the solutions given in this forum and changed `Organize > Folder and Search Options: View Tab` from the default of the option **"Always show icons, never thumbnails"** from checked to unchecked.

I did a disk cleanup, checking only the thumbnails checkbox. Nothing works. The icons to the left of the file names are folders for folders and a generic picture of a mountain for every `jpeg`. I used to see small images of the actual pictures, both at one time on this system and also when I had Windows XP. I'm at loss what else to try.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing it from Group Policy Edit `[gpedit]`.

`User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Explorer` inside this you will se list, serach inside that you will find it something related to thumbnails . i cant tell you exact one coz my Win7 doesnt have gpedit, and i dont need it.

Comment: This answer doesn't tell us very much. What settings should he look at in group policy? How would he go about changing them?

Comment: `User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Explorer` inside this you will se list, serach inside that you will find it something related to `thumbnails` . i cant tell you exact one coz my Win7 doesnt have gpedit, and i dont need it.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer @SlimGG to include that information. Thanks.

Comment: Where do I find User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Explorer? I searched Windows 7 help on "User Configuration" and didn't find anything, so I don't know what to do about that whole path.

Comment: @Michael inside Group Policy Editor `[gpedit]`

Comment: OK, I brought up gpedit from a cmd window. I set "Turn off the display of thumbnails and only display icons" to Disabled. I set "Turn off the display of thumbnails and only display icons on network folders" to Disabled. I set "Turn off the caching of thumbnails in hidden thumbs.db files" to Disabled. (All three had been set to Not Configured.) Made no difference. All thumbnails for image files are st5ill represented by a generic icon, not by miniatures of the pictures. Any more ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Restarting the computer did not help, either.

Comment: More information: Curiously, there is a file summary when I click on a file across the bottom of the Explorer window that does show a miniature preview of the image plus information about the file. But the image to the left of the filename itself is still a generic icon. What I would _like_ to see, of course, is an image to replace that icon to the left of every filename.